# User acessando com apenas um email

Tags: php, javascript

Queria ter um direcionamento, seja javascript, php ou MySQL..
Pra mim poder desenvolver e ter mais idéias.

Bom, eu tenho um sistema de login e senha normal, com banco de dados etc.

A minha ideia era a seguinte:
Com somente um e-mail poder ter vários acessos. Oque diferencia é a senha(que no caso seria um pk).

Exemplo: 
Email@Email.com
Senha01 - Essa conta direciona pra uma conta ADM

Email@Email.com
Senha02 - Essa conta direciona pra um user normal.

Andei pesquisando e encontrei algo relacionado sso, porém não entendi muito bem.

Comment: Bem, não acredito que caiba uma "resposta" aqui. Em primeiro lugar, *na minha opinião*, sua ideia viola uma questão básica de segurança que é tornar conhecida a senha do usuário (para poder comparar a qual nível de acesso ela se refere); isto sugere que a senha não terá o mínimo de criptografia e que será armazenada em texto plano (mesmo que convertida para base64 ou equivalente). Acredito que o mais comum é dar ao usuário a participação em níveis de acesso ou áreas do sistema (ou mesmo módulos). Talvez você possa também criar um terceiro campo como "nome" para fazer essa separação, q n é bom

Comment: Você pode definir o seguinte: o usuário se cadastra uma vez, ao fazer login ele pode ter uma página para adicionar contas, ele insere o novo nome e a senha da conta e ao fazer o processamento de dados, você cria uma coluna como real_id, se referindo a conta principal. Não use a senha como PK e sim o ID como PK. Assim, ao fazer login, o usuário poderá selecionar qual conta deseja usar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olha, você pode fazer isso armazenando as senhas criptografas no BD, e na hora de consultar vc consulta pelo usuário e testa a senha inserida para cada linha retornada do banco. Existe essa função do PHP: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.crypt.php que eu acho muito boa, é unidirecional, ou seja, não tem método para descriptografar. Veja na documentação como ela funciona.

Porém isso pode gerar VÁRIOS problemas pra você, como: e se vc colocar a mesma senha para os dois usuários ou 3 ou 4 com o mesmo e-mail? Apenas para gerar regras de permissão no sistema? Muito trabalho/código para pouco benefício. Não acho que vale a pena investir nessa abordagem.

Portanto, sugiro:

Se você quer fazer um nível de permissão sugiro que crie duas tabelas:

```
User(id, email, senha)
Permissoes(id_user, admin, recepcao, id_user references User(id))
```

Onde `admin` e `recepcao` seriam do tipo boolean para determinar se o usuário tem a permissão de admin, recepcao, e assim por diante. Quantas permissões forem necessárias.

Ou pode criar apenas uma tabela com as duas coisas:

```
User(id, email, senha, admin, recepcao)
```

Dessa forma se um usuário tiver mais de uma permissão, você pode dar múltiplas escolhas de páginas para ele acessar. Simples e de fácil manutenção.